# how to add all numbers from a row in a two dimensional array java

Tags: java, eclipse, multidimensional-array, addition

I am writing Java in Eclipse IDE, I have this 2D array:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int[][] fravaer18S = {
{ 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0 },
{ 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0 }};
```

In another Class, I am supposed to write code so that a person can give a column number, and all numbers from that column is then added together.

So f.ex. a person gives row 3, and the code returns 15.

This stump of code was given:

```
 public int samletFravaer(int[][] fravaer, int elevNr) {
    // TODO
    return -1;
```

How do I code that? And what  do I need to write in my main?

Comment: Homework? Do you know the basics of Java programming? Loops, conditions, arrays, ...?

Comment: Why would the code return 3. The addition of your numbers on column 3 of the matrix is 1 or 2 depending on which number you start indexing from.

Comment: Its not the column no. Its row no.

Answer (score 0):

Add boundry conditions or exception handling on your own.

```
public int samletFravaer(int[][] fravaer, int elevNr) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < fravaer[elevNr].length; i++) {
      sum += fravaer[elevNr][i];
    }
    return sum;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could also be done using foreach loop

```
public static int samletFravaer(int[][] fravaer, int elevNr){
    int ri = 0;
    for(int i: fravaer[elevNr]){
        ri += i;
    }
    return ri;
}
```